# How do i use a variable in firebase storage ref

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I have built a function to get the download URL for the specified ref which can be found below:

```
function download_file(val) {
 //val = Uploads/Files/swxhlhae-tech-logo.png inside of the function because i have it logged..
 console.log(val)
 var storage = firebase.storage();
 const value = 'Uploads/Files/' + val
                                            
 storage.ref('Uploads/Files/swxhlhae-tech-logo.png').getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
 
                                            
 console.log(url)
                                            
                                             
 }).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error)
 });
}
```

EDIT:

```
  var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref('Uploads/Files/');
  var rowIndex = 1;
  
  databaseRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
  var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
  var childData = childSnapshot.val();
  
  
  
  //childKey
  //childData.FirstName
  var html = '<li class="collection-item">';
    html += '<div class="row">';
    html += '<div class="col s9">';
    html += '<p class="collections-title">' + childData.FileName + '</p>';
    html += '<p class="collections-content">' + 'Uploaded: ' + childData.Uploaded + '</p>';
    html += '</div>';
    html += '<div class="col s3">';
    html += '<a href="#" onclick="download_file(this.title)" title=" '+ childData.DownloadName + '">' + '<span class="task-cat blue">Download</span></a>';
    html += '<a href="#" title="' + childKey + '" onclick="delete_file(this.title)"><span id="' + childKey + '" class="task-cat red">Delete</span></a>';
    
    html += '</div>';
    html += '</div>';
    html += '</li>';
    

    document.getElementById('files').innerHTML += html;
    
    
  
    });
  });
```

EDIT : This code above this generates html, i made it so it makes a title on the button, when clicked it grabs the buttons title value, and then it passes that (val) variable to that function above, and then goes from there

And Basically when i use the example above it wrks just fine...  but when i use a variable called (value) it tells me that there is a 404 file doesnt exist... but when i look at the (value) variable and the original ref that i typed into the function... there the exact same why isnt it working? Why cant i use the variable?

Comment: Can you explain how the link applies here @Aqdas? This question seems to be about the `this` value in the HTML, while the link is about asynchronous loading. While there may be some similarity (as they're both about *when* a piece of code gets evaluated), I don' think they're all that similar, let alone duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `this.tile` in `onclick="download_file(this.title)"` is evaluated when the user clicks the element, and at that point `this` is a different object. The easiest way to fix this is to inject the correct value into the `childData.DownloadName` immediately when you render the HTML:

```
html += `<a href="#" onclick="download_file('${childData.DownloadName}')" title="${childData.DownloadName}"><span class="task-cat blue">Download</span></a>`;
```

Comment: I Pasted your example in the spot of my error and that lined of code is filled with errors according to chromes log?

Comment: But I Get What You Mean

Comment: Thank You So Much!! I Really Do Appreciate It!